# Which one is more optimized class level array vs array in recursive method

Tags: java, android, performance, recursion, arraylist

I have two options.

1. Declare array at class level.
2. Create this array some where and call recursive method and after required operation return this array.

Now consider that i am using a background thread which loads some data from server and saves in array like

```
private int MAX_VALUE = 50;
private int currentPage = 0;
```

Example for option 1 array is declared at class level

```
// array declaration at class level.
List<SomeClass> array = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();

public void testMethod(int size) {

            new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer>() {

                @Override
                protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                    // some network operation which takes page number
                    // returns some data and save it to array
                    List<SomeClass> data = someNetworkOperation(params[0]);
                    array.addAll(data);
                    // size loaded data 
                    return data.size();
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
                    if (result.intValue() == MAX_VALUE) {
                        // data couldn't load completely load next page
                        testMethod(++currentPage);
                    } else{
                        // date loaded use array for next operation
                        return;
                    }
                };  
            }.execute(new Integer[] { size });
    }
```

Second option use recursive every call pass array to next recursive step like

```
public List<SomeClass> useTestMethod() {
        return testMethod(currentPage, new ArrayList<SomeClass>());
    }

    public List<SomeClass> testMethod(int size, final List<SomeClass> array) {

        new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer>() {

            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                // some network operation which returns some data and save it to
                List<SomeClass> data = someNetworkOperation(params[0]);
                array.addAll(data);
                return data.size();
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
                if (result.intValue() == MAX_VALUE) {
                    testMethod(++currentPage, array);
                } else {
                    // data loaded pass array to do next step
                }
            };    
        }.execute(new Integer[] { size });
        return array;
    }
```

Question is that which solution is most effective in terms of memory allocation and performance. Whats your thoughts??

Comment: You could profile it and not guess :-) . Generally speaking recursion is considered wasteful.

Comment: Consider in broad level array may have more than thousand elements. Than declaring array at class level is usefull??

Comment: Are you choosing beteween batching and retrieving everything once? Or between storing the (same amount of..) data statically or dynamically?

Comment: Consider that i am requesting server to send me the messages on behalf of current page and user server can not send all the messages once at a time but supports paging request once at a time

Answer (score 0):

From the memory allocation perspective there is no difference, unless the array is always (!) very small and can be stack allocated (in method 2).

Otherwise, the dominant factor will be the recursion. As the JVM currently does not implement tail recursion elimination, the first method will be the most efficient one.

Answer (score 0):

> According to my knowledge Second option you are trying is wrong.

**Reason**

Suppose you have an `array of 2000 elements` ,It is calling an AsyncTask(means background operation) and after just starting your AsyncTask it execute the next return statement whereas your AsyncTask is still working on it. So it will not return the full array.

```
public List<SomeClass> testMethod(int size, final List<SomeClass> array) {

        new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer>() {

            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                // some network operation which returns some data and save it to
                List<SomeClass> data = someNetworkOperation(params[0]);
                array.addAll(data);
                return data.size();
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
                if (result.intValue() == MAX_VALUE) {
                    testMethod(++currentPage, array);
                } else {
                    // data loaded pass array to do next step
                }
            };    
        }.execute(new Integer[] { size });
        return array;
    }
```